# ruby on rails merge two yaml files in a unique yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, merge, yaml

i have 2 yml files:

```
#1.yml
devise:
  omniauth:
    app_id: "some"
    app_secret: "aa"
    app_name: "aaa"

#2.yml
secret_token: "qqqq"
devise:
  omniauth:
    app_foobar: "some"
```

i want to obtain a unique yml file like this:

```
#merged.yml
devise:
  omniauth:
    app_id: 
    app_secret:
    app_name: 
    app_foobar:
secret_token:
```

i want to merge the files without the value, only with the key. Is possible with ruby and rails?

Comment: It's quite possible.  How have _you_ tried to do it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i haven't try becouse i have no idea!

Comment: Well I would start by looking at the [documentation for YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html), which lets you read and write to YAML files. If you have a specific question around that, we'd be happy to answer it for you.

Comment: @user1066183 what was your solution?

Comment: I have found no solution

Answer (score 0):

I would turn them into hashes, merge them, .to_yaml the merged hash and write it to file. YAML may already have a merge method. You should install pry then use it to check out the methods in YAML, or ruby-doc. Then in pry you can mess around interactively which makes developing a solution much easier.